# Return Non-empty Output: grep httpd | head -1 | tail -c 9

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, tr

I need some value returned.
it can be anything.

this code returns "   08:10" if the service is running.

```
ps -eo comm,etime | grep httpd | head -1 | tail -c 9
```

but what if the service is not running ?

```
service httpd stop
```

and let's try again:

```
ps -eo comm,etime | grep httpd | head -1 | tail -c 9
```

absolutely nothing.

this is a problem for me. my php array expects something to work with.

how can i.. return some sort of a something instead of nothing ?

without resorting to huge complexities.

even the following scenario would be okay with me.

simply appending or prepanding a chracter to the output regardless what the output is..

perhaps that would be less stress for the computer ?

simply append "0" to whatever the output is. even if it is nothing (empty)

Comment: Try to append `| grep . || echo "no match"`.

Comment: Why do you output `comm` in the first place when you just want `etime`?

Comment: Well, what you want to do is to write a shell script which (1) picks up the pidfile of http and get's the pid from it, (2) checks if PID is still running and if yes, (3) runs `ps -o etime= -p PID || echo '00:00'`

Comment: @Suspended If you want to delete your question for some reason, either vote to delete it or flag it for moderator attention rather than filling the post with "deleted."

Comment: Do not vandalise your posts please.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for `pgrep`:

```
pgrep httpd
```

If the process is running the exit status (`$?`) will be `0`, along with the stat on STDOUT. If the process is not running the exit status will be `1`.

If you want, match for the whole command line:

```
pgrep -f httpd
```

If you don't need the STDOUT:

```
pgrep -f httpd >/dev/null
```

---

If you want something on STDOUT when the process is not running, tack a short circuit evaluation for the failed case:

```
pgrep httpd || echo NO
```

This will output `NO` on STDOUT when the process is not running.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be so complicated :

```
ret=$(ps -eo comm,etime | grep httpd | head -1 | tail -c 9)
if [ -z "$ret" ];then
 echo "What you want"
else
 echo "${ret}"
fi
```

Comment: @Suspended. My previous answer is wrong. Not really. A if with pipe is quite difficult (even with tree).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @heemayl that pgrep would be a better choice. However, this might help:

```
{ ps -eo comm,etime; echo "httpd not running"; } | grep -m 1 httpd | cut -d- -f2
```

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your comment with regard to `printf`.